# how do you read text files off the internet in Android 4.0.3

Tags: android

I am a relatively new Android programmer and I was wondering how you could get read text off the internet in 4.0.3. I keep finding code that gives me a Network on Main exception: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html and was wondering if anyone could provide me some sample code to get around this, for reference I got the code I tried to use here: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/04/read-text-file-from-internet-using-java.html. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you added the Internet permission(`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`) to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Honeycomb and Ice Cream Sandwich (i.e. Android 3.0+) , you cannot connect to the internet in the main thread (`onCreate()`, `onPause()`, `onResume()` etc.), and you have to instead start a new thread. The reason why this has changed is because network operations can make the app wait for a long time, and if you're running them in the main thread, the whole application becomes unresponsive. If you try to connect from the main thread, Android will throw a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

To bypass this, you can run networking code from a new thread, and use `runOnUiThread()` to do things in the main thread, such as update the user interface. Generally, you can do something like:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
  public onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate();

    // Create thread
    Thread networkThread = new Thread() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          // this is where your networking code goes
          // I'm declaring the variable final to be accessible from runOnUiThread
          final String result = someFunctionThatUsesNetwork();

          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              // this is where you can update your interface with your results
              TextView myLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myLabel);
              myLabel.setText(result);
            }
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.e("App", "IOException thrown", e);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I exactly tried the same way but did not have any success. My machine is Working Behind Proxy, and the target version is 4.0.Getting Response in HTML which says "CACHE ACCESS DENIED" , when this is served as an input for Parsing it's throwing XMLPullParserException.... I have the 2.6.5 version of KSOAP. I want to know it's possible or not, perhaps some suggestion would be really helpful. It seems lot of questions (like mine) are unanswered in SO .

Answer (score 0):

You need to complete an HTTP Request. There are a lot of examples available on line. Try [here](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=android%20http%20request%20example&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) for starts.