# How Can GetResponse From The web-Service Using Android

Tags: android, web-services

Hi I tried to Read Any Data From A Web-Service Using Android 
But Every Time Tried I Face A problem

Today I Try To Read A Web-Service From 3schools site

use this Code

```
package com.example.lo2i03;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
//import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    private static String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL";
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
         SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);             
         request.addProperty("Celsius","32"); 
         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
         envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
         envelope.dotNet = true;
         try
         {
               HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);          
               androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);             
               SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
               tv.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
         }
         catch (Exception e) 
         {
              tv.setText("Error");
         }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

With Knowledge that I Added The Permission to Manifest To Access The Internet

### It GOES Directly To A catch Block ...

The Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lo2i03"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.lo2i03.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

---

Android Version : 4.2 - 4.2

---

### LogCat Error Looks Like

```
11-24 01:28:29.065: E/Trace(13408): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-24 01:28:29.195: D/AndroidRuntime(13408): Shutting down VM
11-24 01:28:29.195: W/dalvikvm(13408): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x412862a0)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lo2i03/com.example.lo2i03.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:76)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:146)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at com.example.lo2i03.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5191)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
11-24 01:28:29.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13408):    ... 11 more
```

---

NEW LOGCAT (1.0)

```
11-24 16:28:28.850: E/Trace(25195): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-24 16:28:28.995: D/libEGL(25195): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
11-24 16:28:28.995: D/libEGL(25195): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
11-24 16:28:29.000: D/libEGL(25195): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
11-24 16:28:29.000: D/(25195): Device driver API match
11-24 16:28:29.000: D/(25195): Device driver API version: 10
11-24 16:28:29.000: D/(25195): User space API version: 10 
11-24 16:28:29.000: D/(25195): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Wed Sep 12 17:53:53 KST 2012 
11-24 16:28:29.030: D/OpenGLRenderer(25195): Enabling debug mode 0
11-24 16:28:31.215: D/dalvikvm(25195): GC_CONCURRENT freed 214K, 10% free 12330K/13575K, paused 13ms+13ms, total 40ms
11-24 16:28:39.615: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25195): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
11-24 16:28:39.615: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25195): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
11-24 16:28:39.615: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(25195): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
```

With knowledge That I Use (WiFi) TO Access The Internet .

Any Advice?

Comment: Put your error log. What is the android version? Look like you is trying to make http request inside a thread UI, try to move your code to an AsyncTask.

Comment: @dougcunha
How Can I Put The Error Log
Do You Mean A LogCat ??

Comment: Yes, copy the lines of logcat and put then here.

Comment: @dougcunha Thanks You , I put The LogCat In The Main POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetworkOnMainThreadException means that you is running http request code inside a UI thread.

try something like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
         final SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);             
         request.addProperty("Celsius","32"); 
         final SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
         envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
         envelope.dotNet = true;
         new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
            SoapObject obj;

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                   //here you can do your background network job
                try
                 {
                       HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);          
                       androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);             
                       obj = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

                       return true;
                 }
                 catch (Exception e) 
                 {
                     e.printStackTrace();   
                         return false;                    
                 }
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
             //here you can do your UI job
                if (!result) 
                    tv.setText("Error");
                else 
                    tv.setText(obj.getProperty(0).toString());
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
        }.execute();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks ,,But It Gives Me An Error Here
`tv.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());`

Comment: In `getProperty(0)` Property

Comment: I think it conflicted with the 
` SoapObject result;`
And With
the parameter of the onPostExecute()  << (Method)

Does it Correct ?? ,,
but even that (I tried To change the names) but the problem stils but this time gives me an ("error") << in the text view
that mean (the result value was false).

Comment: I changed the code. Add the e.printStackTrace(); on catch block and copy here the LogCat!

Comment: The Code Goes To Catch Block And Show Me ("Error") On TextView .
I Placed A New LogCat In The Main POST.

Regards .

Comment: I looked up at this question Here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050838/how-do-you-read-text-files-off-the-internet-in-android-4-0-3], he says the internet cannot be accesed from the `OnCreate()` Method ,,, Is there Any Relation Between This And That .

Comment: Internet should use another thread than UI thread. It is done by using an AsyncTask like my suggestion. The error now is something else related to obj = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse()

Comment: I Think , The Error Was Not In The Code .

It Might be from these ::

1- Web-Service It Self .
2- Jar Files Or Permissions (With Knowledge That I Add Internet Permission To The Manifest File , And Add KSOAP2 JAR TO 'libs' folder and add to the build path) .
-------
Now I will run the app on the emulator instead of My Phone To See What Will Happen .

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope. dotNet= true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);                    
        SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();          
        String r = result.toString();
        return r;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

if you need returns object or arraylist, i can post solution...

Comment: Thanks For The Code But Also It Doesn't Work With Me
It Gives Me The Same Error In My Device (Unfortunaly,[app_name] Has Stopped)

Any Advice ?\

Comment: I tried and applied  more than 10 tutorials ,, no one success with me ,, can you please give another Way To Do that 
like Connect to sql server directly without using web-service

Comment: could you Please Give The Code to Receive An ArrayList And DataTable :)

Answer (score 1):

to get object from soap webservice:

```
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope. dotNet= true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_VERATENDIMENTO, envelope);                    
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();            
        YourClass yourClass = new YourClass();
        if (result == null){
            return null;
        } else {
            yourClass.setName(result.getProperty("name").toString());
            yourClass.setEmail(result.getProperty("email").toString());
            return yourClass;               
        }                       
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }               
    return null;
```

to return arraylist do:

```
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope. dotNet= true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_VERMENSAGENS, envelope);                    
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();            

        List<YourClassObject> yourList = new ArrayList<YourClassObject>();
        if (result == null){
            return null;
        } else {
            for(int i =0; i < result.getPropertyCount(); i++){
                SoapObject soap = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(i);
                YourClassObject yourClass = new YourClassObject();
                yourClass.setName(soap.getProperty("name").toString()));
                yourClass.setEmail(soap.getProperty("email").toString()));
                yourList.add(yourClass);
            }
            return yourList;
        }                       
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }               
    return null;
```

Comment: Should I also Use `AsyncTask` To Do The Operation ?

Comment: I using Android Annotations, for AsyncTask i can only call @Background  above on the method, AsynTask with Android Annotations, very easy, fast, simple...

Answer (score 1):

add permision to internet in your manifest file

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

and then on your Activity where are you running your http request add this lines just before setContentView like this

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
```