# Error With Calling A Web-Service And Receiving Data

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I Try To Receive Data From A Web-Service
Using This Code But An Fatal-Error Occurred

```
package com.example.lo2i05;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    private static String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL";
    private TextView tv;
    private Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
         btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
         btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
         {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
         {

                final SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);             
                 request.addProperty("Celsius","32"); 
                 final SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                 envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                 envelope.dotNet = true;
                 try 
                    {
                            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);                    
                            SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();          
                            String r = result.toString();
                            tv.setText(r);
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                           tv.setText("1");
                    }
                    catch (XmlPullParserException e) 
                    {
                           tv.setText("2");
                    }   
         }
        });

       } 
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

This Is A LogCat

```
11-24 23:04:03.100: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1155): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
11-24 23:04:03.100: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1155): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
11-24 23:04:03.100: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1155): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
11-24 23:04:08.135: D/GestureDetector(1155): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0
11-24 23:04:08.165: D/AndroidRuntime(1155): Shutting down VM
11-24 23:04:08.165: W/dalvikvm(1155): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x412862a0)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:188)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.openOutputStream(ServiceConnectionSE.java:109)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:157)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:96)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at com.example.lo2i05.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:46)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4223)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17275)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
11-24 23:04:08.170: E/AndroidRuntime(1155):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-24 23:09:16.970: I/Process(1155): Sending signal. PID: 1155 SIG: 9
```

Android Version : 4.2 (Jelly Bean).

## I Added A Permission To the Manifest To Access The Internet .

New CODE (1.0)

```
package com.example.lo2i05;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    private static String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL";
    private TextView tv;
    private Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
         btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
         btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
         {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
         {
                 final SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);             
                 request.addProperty("Celsius","32"); 
                 final SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
                 envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                 envelope.dotNet = true;
                 new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
                    SoapObject obj;

                    @Override
                    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                           //here you can do your background network job
                        try{ HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);          
                               androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);             
                               obj = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                               return true;  }
                         catch (Exception e)  {e.printStackTrace();   
                                 return false;}}
                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                     //here you can do your UI job
                        if (!result) 
                            tv.setText("Error");
                        else 
                            tv.setText(obj.getProperty(0).toString());
                        super.onPostExecute(result);
                    }
                }.execute();
         }
        });

       } 
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

=======================================

LogCat

```
11-24 23:37:34.120: E/Trace(2671): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-24 23:37:34.235: D/libEGL(2671): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
11-24 23:37:34.240: D/libEGL(2671): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
11-24 23:37:34.240: D/libEGL(2671): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
11-24 23:37:34.245: D/(2671): Device driver API match
11-24 23:37:34.245: D/(2671): Device driver API version: 10
11-24 23:37:34.245: D/(2671): User space API version: 10 
11-24 23:37:34.245: D/(2671): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Wed Sep 12 17:53:53 KST 2012 
11-24 23:37:34.275: D/OpenGLRenderer(2671): Enabling debug mode 0
11-24 23:37:35.895: D/GestureDetector(2671): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 2 mFalseSizeCnt:0
11-24 23:37:50.615: W/System.err(2671): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive cannot be cast to org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
11-24 23:37:50.615: W/System.err(2671):     at com.example.lo2i05.MainActivity$1$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:48)
11-24 23:37:50.615: W/System.err(2671):     at com.example.lo2i05.MainActivity$1$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
11-24 23:37:50.620: W/System.err(2671):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-24 23:37:50.620: W/System.err(2671):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-24 23:37:50.620: W/System.err(2671):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-24 23:37:50.620: W/System.err(2671):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-24 23:37:50.620: W/System.err(2671):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-24 23:37:50.620: W/System.err(2671):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-24 23:37:50.620: W/System.err(2671):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-24 23:38:05.935: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(2671): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
11-24 23:38:05.935: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(2671): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
11-24 23:38:05.935: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(2671): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
```

Comment: Do your network related task in `AsyncTask`

Comment: No I Don't Use A `AsyncTask`
Because I Understand We Use this only when i Wanaa To Establish An Internet Access on the `OnCreate()` Method

Comment: you are using Internet for accessing webservice

Comment: You cannot and should not perform any network operation on the main thread. You need to use an AsyncTask.

Comment: Thank you So Much Really I used A `AsyncTask`
but Also I have no value returned to me A this
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532554/how-can-getresponse-from-the-web-service-using-android/13536812#13536812]

Comment: @Loai.Alhalabi I have added answer please check below

Comment: @kamil - Thank you ,, Before I Use your code
look at the new code i wrote it (code (1.0)) and at the new logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to asynchronously like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL";
private TextView tv;
private Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
     btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
     btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
     {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
     {
      new MyTask().execute();
      }
    });
  }
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    ProgressDialog progress;
        String response = "";

      public void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
      }

    @Override
    protected Stirng doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
             final SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);             
             request.addProperty("Celsius","32"); 
             final SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
             envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
             envelope.dotNet = true;
             try 
                {
                        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);                    
                        SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();          
                         response = result.toString();

                }
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                 response = "1";
                }
                catch (XmlPullParserException e) 
                {
                 response = "2";
                } 

        return response;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String res) {

                if(!(res.equalsIgnoreCase("")))
                {
                 tv.setText(res);
                }

      }
    }
 }
```

Just try this now

Comment: you can add this code in the same activity, just under the activity not in onCreate, and try call this at onClick

Comment: @Loai.Alhalabi were this help you?

Comment: Actually , i don't know Exactly Where should I put the code :(

Comment: I appreciate you :) ,,,

Now IF I Need To Retrieve Any Thing From Web-Service I Have To Use This Way ??

Comment: Yes, as what are you doing is just making a request in UI thread and in the latest api level it not allow to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html. As per official doc if you are using Honeycomb SDK or above your should not put network operation on the main/UI thread. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop threads, but it's heavily discouraged since it would block the UI and can cause ANR.

You need to use an background thread or `AsyncTask` for network operation to avoid getting this exception.

As a general rule always put time consuming task in background thread or `AsyncTask`.

EDIT:

Change following line in your code

```
obj = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
```

to

```
SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
```

Comment: This is better as a comment since you only link to the developer docs and don't use more than a partial sentence.

Comment: How about now? Use "edit" to turn this into a meaningful answer or remove it with "delete".

Comment: Thank you So Much Really I used A `AsyncTask`
but Also I have no value returned to me A this
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532554/how-can-getresponse-from-the-web-service-using-android/13536812#13536812]
----------
I post this Question now to perform same task but different code .
But Still Not Working :(

Comment: first please use the `AsyncTask` then put the stack trace in the exception block to check the cause of the exception and then please share the new logcat..

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar  Please Refer to the main post I Placed the code (code (1.0))
that contains a AsyncTask With A LogCat